# swiftui 3-view stack layout, middle stack taking up space

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to use SwiftUI to build something along the lines of a header/content/footer with a `VStack`. I'd like the header and footer to take up 10% each of the height of the screen, and the content to expand to fill up the rest. This pattern could be useful for things other than header/content/footer, so if there's already something that implements this pattern (middle view expanding, or something along those lines), that would be great...

This is probably super simple to experienced swift devs, but I can't seem to find an example of it anywhere.

Any advice/pointers/code would be greatly appreciated!

My existing, super-simple code, with all of my experiments removed:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Header()
            Content()
            Footer()
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0,
               maxWidth: .infinity,
               minHeight: 0,
               maxHeight: .infinity,
               alignment: Alignment.topLeading)
        .border(Color.red)

    }
}

struct Header: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            Text("Header")
        }
        .padding()
        .border(Color.blue)
    }
}

struct Content: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            Text("Content")
        }
        .padding()
        .border(Color.black)
    }
}

struct Footer: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack() {
            Text("Footer")
        }
        .padding()
        .border(Color.green)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may use `GeometryReader` in your case:

```swift
struct HeaderContentFooter: View {

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { geometry in

            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Rectangle() // header
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .frame(height: geometry.size.height / 10)

                Rectangle() // content, which fill up everything with VStack

                Rectangle() // footer
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                    .frame(height: geometry.size.height / 10)
            }

        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

    }
}
```

the result should be:
[image]

Comment: Hey, this is great, thanks! Is there something special about the `Rectangle` view that makes this work? If I change the `Rectangle` to `Text` (or `HStack`, or whatever), it no longer works. If you change the middle `Rectangle` to `Text("Content")`, it no longer fills up the space. Thanks again!

Comment: @Hoopes there are several solutions to achieve this:
use the same technique: ```Text("hello").frame(height: geometry.size.height * 0.9)``` ;
put everything in the middle into view, which takes up all the space by default (such as ```ScrollView```, ```GeometryReader```, etc.);
put everything into ```ZStack``` and use the same ```Rectangle()```. as example:
```ZStack {
        Rectangle().foregroundColor(.white) // you can google how to change color with colorScheme
         Text("hello!")
}```

Comment: @Hoopes answering your question: yes, ```Rectangle``` takes up all the space. By the way, I remembered another solution: put middle View into ```VStack``` and use ```Spacer()``` at the top and at the bottom (```VStack { Spacer(); Text("1"); Spacer() }```)

Comment: Thanks again - fiddling with spacers enough got me far enough to where I'm headed. Still a little counterintuitive (especially order of things, like `frame`), but I guess that's how you learn.